# Help installing light switch please

Tags: wiring, switch, light

Ignore the wire already attached. I started before realizing there were two black wires. I was able to determine the hot wire by turning on the circuit breaker and using a non contact voltage tester.

I am trying to install a single pole [Eaton switch](https://www.lowes.com/pd/Eaton-Single-Pole-White-LED-Rocker-Light-Switch/1002944146) from Lowes. I believe the ground is on the bottom. The hot should be on the top.

I have no idea which other wire goes where.

[image]

Comment: I cannot ignore the fact that you connected a bare ground wire to a screw intended for an insulated hot conductor. That's a big red flag on your qualification for this project. Or that you wrapped the wire backward on the screw. You really need to do some reading before you attempt work like this.

Comment: Short answer: Blacks to the side screws in any configuration. Bare ground to the _green_ screw.

Comment: For my future knowledge, how can I tell which wire is ground and which is hot? The old switch was not a rocker style switch, it was a recalled motion sensing switch over 10 years old.

Comment: Ground wires in cables are almost always bare. In conduit they tend to be green. But when you do some reading of a reputable source you'll learn all that.

Comment: If that is the way you found that switch wired and not what you did(big no-no), I would have an electrician in to find other very bad surprises.  If there is one there are others.  If you wired this up like this, still get an electrician before you kill yourself.

Comment: At a minimum, please search the internet for [how to wire a switch](https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffab&q=how+to+wire+a+switch&ia=web) so you've got at least a basic knowledge. We'd really like you to be alive to come back to ask other questions...

Comment: what reputable sources would you recommend to read?

Comment: Hot wire colours are everything except bare, green(both ground) and most of time white.  White can be confusing since neutral must be white, but white is not always neutral.  It should be labelled with a colour when not used as a neutral, 75% of the people too lazy to label/mark it(me included sometimes).

Answer (score 0):

The bare wire is ground, and you have it WRONG.

It goes into the top screw.

[image: ground]

The black wires can go on any of the two side screws the order does not matter.

Comment: Please, for the sake of the OP's life, be _VERY_ precise in what you consider the "top screw" to be. Better yet, give him colors as a reference. Especially since the colors for ground are obvious and consistent.

Comment: Better, thank you. Many switches/receptacles have that screw on the bottom when the device is installed with the writing right side up. Stating the fact that the ground connects to the GREEN screw makes it much more difficult for someone to screw up.